# Caja - Respawning too rapidly

Tags: linux-mint, desktop

I had a problem with *wxPython* displaying on Mint 17.2 64-bit. This was fixed by installing *gtk2-engines-oxygen*. However the first time I re-booted after doing so *caja* started re-spawning more than once a second. The desktop icons are not displaying either so I think the issues are linked. How can I overcome this as it has made the laptop unusable. Uninstalling *caja* stops this (no desktop) but reinstalling re-introduces the problem. A search on a number of websites has given me no idea of how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by edittinh /usr/share/applications/caja.desktop from:-

```
Exec=caja
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
```

to:-

```
Exec=caja -n
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
```

However it is a mystery as to why the problem suddenly popped up...